# Heroku scheduler winter, summer time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm deploying RoR application in Heroku.

Using, **redis**, **sidekiq** and **sendgrid** my application delivering some emails with daily reports at 7 am CET.

For this purpose, I configured 6:00 AM UTC schedule invoking rake task who put the email in the sideqik mailers queue.

I am having problems with daylight saving times. My emails are delivered differents time in summer vs winter.

*There is a way to fix this issue without change manually TZ every winter or summer?*

*There is a way of set TZ which is aware of daylight saving times?*